# Multicast delegate with double return type, only returns the last method's result, and not All method's results

Tags: c#, delegates, invoke, multicastdelegate

I am new to this topic and wanted to know is there a way that I could get all method's result and not only the last method's result while using a return type for multicast delegate?

Here is my code:

```cs
class Program
    {
        public delegate double rectangleDelegate (double Width, double Heigth);
        class Rectangle
        {
            public double GetPerimeter(double Width, double Heigth)
            {
                return 2 * (Width + Heigth);
            }
            public double GetArea(double Width, double Heigth)
            {
                return Width * Heigth;
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();

            rectangleDelegate obj = rectangle.GetArea;
            obj += rectangle.GetPerimeter;

            Console.WriteLine(obj(4, 2));

        }
    }
```

I tried with `void` for my methods and delegates and printing the results. In this case I could see both methods output on console. But when using a return type like `double` I only get last methods output.

Can I do something to get each method's return and store it in a variable or a list?
Or is it totally wrong approach to expect such a thing from multicast delegates?

Comment: From the docs "When the signature of the methods invoked by a delegate includes a return value, the delegate returns the return value of the last element in the invocation list." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate?view=net-7.0#remarks

Comment: @Charlieface that helped me a lot in understanding the delegate concepts. thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get all of the return values like this. The only way I know to do it is a little hacky uses `GetInvocationList`:

```
rectangleDelegate obj = rectangle.GetArea;
obj += rectangle.GetPerimeter;

foreach(var del in obj.GetInvocationList())
{
    var result = (double)del.DynamicInvoke(4, 2);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Of course, this is a little dangerous as it assumes the delegates of a specific format. You could coerce the delegate to the type you use like this, which means you don't need to use `DynamicInvoke`:

```
foreach(rectangleDelegate del in obj.GetInvocationList())
{
    var result = del(4, 2);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Or a safer version:

```
foreach(var del in obj.GetInvocationList().OfType<rectangleDelegate>())
{
    var result = del(4, 2);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you , that was what I really looked for.

Comment: "Or a safer version" The previous version is no less safe.  You got the value out of a delegate of that same type.  You're only ever casting it back to the exact type you got it from.  Treating it dynamically or checking the type that you already know *for sure* that it is, is not safer, it's just unnecessary work and potentially causing confusion for readers.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach is to change the delegate and to make it add the results to a list:

```cs
public delegate void RectangleDelegate(double Width, double Height,
                                       List<double> results);
```

Without changing the `Rectangle` class we get:

```cs
var rectangle = new Rectangle();
var results = new List<double>();

RectangleDelegate rectDelegate = (w, h, r) => r.Add(rectangle.GetArea(w, h));
rectDelegate += (w, h, r) => r.Add(rectangle.GetPerimeter(w, h));

rectDelegate(4, 2, results);
foreach (double result in results) {
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Note that I am using [lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions) to convert the signature of the rectangle methods into the signature required by the delegate.

Prints

```
8
12
```

---

You could also use a delegate accepting a `Rectangle` parameter allowing a more flexible usage. We also use a `Rectangle2` class having `Width` and `Height` properties instead of such parameters in the methods.

```
public class Rectangle2
{
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }

    public double GetPerimeter()
    {
        return 2 * (Width + Height);
    }

    public double GetArea()
    {
        return Width * Height;
    }
}

public delegate void RectangleDelegate2(Rectangle2 rect, List<double> results);
```

And call it with:

```cs
RectangleDelegate2 rectDelegate = (rect, list) => list.Add(rect.GetArea());
rectDelegate += (rect, list) => list.Add(rect.GetPerimeter());

var results = new List<double>();
rectDelegate(new Rectangle2 { Width = 4, Height = 2 }, results);
rectDelegate(new Rectangle2 { Width = 3, Height = 5 }, results);
foreach (double result in results) {
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

This prints:

```
8
12
15
16
```

Comment: Thank you, this approach really helped me understand the concept.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend avoiding the use of multi cast delegates in this way. It is very uncommon to use multi cast delegates outside of events, and I would need to think a fair bit about why someone would write code like that.

If you want to to call multiple delegates and process the result I would recommend using an explicit list/array:

```
var rectangleDelegateList = new rectangleDelegate[]{ 
    rectangle.GetArea, 
    rectangle.GetPerimeter
}
foreach(var method in rectangleDelegateList ){
    Console.WriteLine(method(4, 2));
}
```

That should be much easier to read and understand. However, I would prefer if the methods returned `Area` and `Length` types respectively, since these should be considered different things.

If you do have an event you would typically pass both input and output in an event argument object:

```
public class MyEventArg{
    public double Width {get; init;}
    public double Height {get; init;}
    public double Result {get;set;}
}
public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> myEvent;

private RaiseEvent(){
    var args = new MyEventArgs(){ Width = 4, Height = 2};
    myEvent?.Invoke(this, args);
    Console.WriteLine(args.Result);
}
```

But this is also a pattern I would be careful with, since you typically do not expect a result value from any event handler. One use case is for things like a closing event, where any event handler is allowed to cancel the closing.